# Creating an Event Listener which listens whether a value in a variable has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I was wondering if there are any modern methods for JavaScript (or maybe using jQuery) to create an event listener which fires a function or a piece of code whenever a variable's value has changed?

```
var test = 1;
```

I want to have an event listener fire whenever the variable `test` is any other value but `1`.

Comment: There is no event model for variables being amended. Why do you need this?

Comment: Well I have a setInterval() function set at 10 milliseconds with many if statements but instead i would rather have a event listener fire my code only whenever the variable's value changes.

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. But that doesn't explain why you believe you need to do this

Comment: Well honestly you are right and I already found effortlessly a better method but the though did come in my mind and so I asked a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object with a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set):

```js
const obj = {
  _test: 1,
  set test(t) {
    t !== 1 && console.log(t); // fire the function
    
    return _test = t;
  }
}

obj.test = 5;
```